# Angular FileSaver with blob and WebAPI . PDF downloaded is blank. But API url returns PDF with content

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, filesaver.js

This is my API for returning a PDF with multiple images . Now when I invoke this with url it perfectly downloads the PDF with images . For eg two pages with images .

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Download(Guid customDocId)
{
    byte[] responseContent = await Task.FromResult(FileNetApiClientFactory.Get(customDocId).DownloadDocument(customDocId, "pdf", true));
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new ByteArrayContent(responseContent),
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
    };
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = string.Concat(customDocId.ToString(), ".pdf") };
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
    return ResponseMessage(response);
}
```

Now from angular I am using blob and `FileSaver` for saving the PDF . So when I download it . Then it  just returns two pages but with no content. But it shows page 1 and page2 but they are blank.

Here is my angular code :

```js
//saveAs method is from FileSaver.js
vm.download = function () {
    documentService.download($scope.customDocumentId).then(function (fileData) {
        var blob = new Blob([fileData], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        saveAs(blob, $scope.customDocumentId + ".pdf");
    }).catch(function () {
    });
}
```

And the service :

```js
function _download(customDocumentId) {
    return Restangular
        .one('customdocument', customDocumentId).one('download')
        .get(null, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
}
```

Does anyone has any idea why is it returning the blank pages when saved with FileSaver, while with direct download it is perfectly fine with all content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to change certain things in Restangular . It was the `responseType` had to be `arrayBuffer` or 'blob'. I haven't tried with arrayBuffer explicitly . The blob responsetype worked for me . The  configurations were missing from restangular. So I made a little change in my service and voila ! It was working.

So the updated Service looks like this now . DocumentServicesRestangular is nothing but a factory wrapper with changed baseurl through RestangularConfigurer.

```
   function _download(customDocumentId) {
            return DocumentServicesRestangular.one('customdocument', customDocumentId).one('download')
                    .withHttpConfig({ responseType: 'blob' }).get();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Like this,

```
$scope.download = function() {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    var requestParams=$scope.downloadObj;
    a.style = "display: none";
     sServices.doAPIRequest(Url)
        .then(function(generateData) {

             var file = new Blob([$scope.base64ToArrayBuffer(generateData)], {
                type : 'application/pdf'
            });
             var fileName="Data";
             var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
             a.href = fileURL;
             a.download = fileName;
             a.click();
        });
};

$scope.base64ToArrayBuffer=function(data)
{
      var binaryString =  window.atob(data);
        var binaryLen = binaryString.length;
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
        for (var i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++)        {
            var ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
            bytes[i] = ascii;
        }
        return bytes;
};
```

Comment: I dont think that download attribute is allowed in all browsers ? That's why trying to avoid that approach

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by changing the $http.get call in my service, so that the response type was set in the config argument:

```
return $http.get(apiTarget, { responseType: 'blob' });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `FileSaver` then this is the right syntax

```
var data = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf;charset=utf-8' });
FileSaver.saveAs(data, filename);
```

Comment: didnt solve my problem . It still returns PDF with blank pages :(

Comment: Also in my application FileSaver.saveAs() isnt there . Its only saveAs() not sure why . I am using FileSaver.min.js